# Google Chat Port Number

Tags: xmpp

Does anyone know which port is used by gtalk.

Comment: I like how the tag for this question also provides the answer.

Comment: It's migrated here from stackoverflow, but wouldn't it have been better to migrate it to superuser?

Comment: He might be opening the company firewall to allow google talk

Comment: Any question that can be answered by typing it into google and reading the results page (not even clicking any links!) is a bad question.

Comment: gtalk no longer exists, and this question popped up for some reason. Not sure what do we do with obsolete questions, but it's not useful to have it open.

Answer (score 9):

From [Google Talk support pages](http://www.google.com/support/talk/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=27930):

> In order to connect to Google Talk and start sending IMs, you'll need to enable TCP connections to talk.google.com on port 5222, or on port 443.

Answer (score 3):

Port 5222 or 443.

That's what Google Talk says here: [Google Talk Support](http://www.google.com/support/talk/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=27930)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.google.com/support/talk/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=27930

> If you're having trouble connecting to
>   Google Talk through your firewall or
>   proxy, it may be because some
>   necessary ports are blocked.
>
> In order to connect to Google Talk and
>   start sending IMs, you'll need to
>   enable TCP connections to
>   talk.google.com on port 5222, or on
>   port 443.
>
> If you'd like to make calls or
>   transfer files through Google Talk,
>   you need to:
>
> ```
> * Enable UDP connections to anywhere on any port; or
> * Enable TCP connections to anywhere on port 443.
> ```
>
> If you're behind a public or corporate
>   network that is blocking these ports
>   or protocols, please contact your
>   local network administrator for
>   further instructions.

Answer (score 1):

you can find this out with wireshark.

Comment: I think people like to get an answer and not a vague direction to an answer

Answer (score 1):

[Required ports to use Google Talk - Google Talk Help](http://www.google.com/support/talk/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=27930)